# Use of config in extjs?

Tags: extjs4

I am having trouble in understanding of the use of config property in ExtJS 4. The documentation says that whenever we keep our properties inside config, ExtJS will generate corresponding getters and setters for the properties. Moreover we can use apply methods if we want to add some logic before setting the property value. But the thing is in spite of adding properties under config we can get and set them without using getters and setters. So config is not helping with encapsulation. Moreover if we want to add some logic before setting our property we can have a custom method, why only use apply methods for that. Here's a sample code..

```
Ext.define('MyApp.data.invoice',{
config:{
    client: '',
    tax: 0.83,
    subtotal: 0,
    total: 0
},

constructor: function(config){
    this.initConfig(config);
},

applySubtotal: function(value){
    this.setTotal(value + value*this.getTax());
    return value;
}
});
```

Here's the use of this class

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
        var invoice = Ext.create('MyApp.data.invoice',{
            client: 'Tuxtuc Inc',
            subtotal: 100,
            total: 80.3
        });
        console.log(invoice.client); //Tuxtuc Inc
        console.log(invoice.getClient); //Tuxtuc

        invoice.setTax(0.16);

        console.log(invoice.getTax()); //0.16

        invoice.subtotal = 1000;

        console.log(invoice.subtotal); // 1000
    });
```